# Getting JSON tree of folders and files (but only with files containing given string)

Tags: python, json, file, directory

I need to get a sort of filtered directory/file structure in JSON format.

Specifically, I need to include only files that contain given string, and to include only directories that contain such files (in themselves, or in some of their descendants).

This code:

```
import os
import json

def path_to_dict(path):
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        d['type'] = "directory"
        d['children'] = [path_to_dict(os.path.join(path,x)) for x in os.listdir\
(path)]
    else:
        d['type'] = "file"
    return d

print json.dumps(path_to_dict('.'), indent=2)
```

gives me nice JSON tree of ALL directories and files, starting from current directory, in the format I want:

```
{
    "type": "directory",
    "name": ".",
    "children": [
    {
      "type": "file", 
      "name": "attribute_container.c"
    }, 
    {
      "type": "file", 
      "name": "node.c"
    }, 
    {
      "type": "directory", 
      "name": "power", 
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "clock_ops.c"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "common.c"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "domain.c"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "domain_governor.c"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "generic_ops.c"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "wakeup.c"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "type": "directory", 
      "name": "regmap", 
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "internal.h"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "Kconfig"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "Makefile"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "regcache-flat.c"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "regmap-spmi.c"
        }, 
        {
          "type": "file", 
          "name": "regmap.c"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "type": "file", 
      "name": "soc.c"
    }, 
    {
      "type": "file", 
      "name": "syscore.c"
    }, 
    {
      "type": "file", 
      "name": "topology.c"
    }, 
    {
      "type": "file", 
      "name": "transport_class.c"
    }   ] }
```

However, I need to have only files that contain given string. Also, only folders that contain such file or files, or some of their descendants contain such file. (so to speak, I need a sort of "pruning")

I know the solution that finds a string in a file:

```
my_file = ...
my_string = ...
infile = open(my_file,"r")

numlines = 0
found = 0
for line in infile:
    numlines += 1
    found += line.count(my_string)
infile.close()

print "%s was found %i times in %i lines", %string, %found, %numlines
```

but i have hard time integrating it in the code from the top of the question.

I appreciate any hint or advice.

Comment: Use os.walk(path) instead of recursive calls to path_to_dict.
 http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/
  
Also after the else, include an if my_string in open(path).read(): then d['type'] = 'file'.  This will only make entries for the files that contain the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't want to rewrite your code by use `os.walk()`.I'll do just some little changes to yours.

The key is use None as sentinel value to prune files and empty `children` list to prune the directory. That implementation is not well written but it show to you the core of how to use the test.

```
import os
import json

def check_in_file(my_file,my_string):
    with open(my_file) as f:
        try:
            return my_string in f.read()
        except:
            return False

def path_to_dict(path, my_string=None):
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        d['type'] = "directory"
        d['children'] = []
        paths = [os.path.join(path,x) for x in os.listdir(path)]
        #Just the children that contains at least a valid file
        for p in paths:
            c = path_to_dict(p, my_string)
            if c is not None:
                d['children'].append(c)
        if not d['children']:
            return None
    else:
        if my_string is not None and not check_in_file(path,my_string):
            return None
        d['type'] = "file"
    return d

print(json.dumps(path_to_dict('.',), indent=2))
print(json.dumps(path_to_dict('.','kkkkk'), indent=2))
```

Comment: For me, the code is gorgeous. I just tested it, a dozen of cases. It works like charm. I had spent hours and hours trying to devise the solution, but now you rescued me. Thank you! The code will be used for important exploratory visualization of C source code!